# How to set-up a .mjs file when importing from cjs?

Tags: import, export, vite, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm using a third party library that provides an `index.js` and `index.mjs` file. The `package.json` has this:

```
"exports": {
   "import": "./index.mjs",
   "require": "./index.js"
},
```

It does NOT contain `"type": "module"` just FYI.

I'm guessing that is letting the code that is using this 3rd party library know that if you use `import` statements to use the `index.mjs` file?

At the very bottom of the compressed `index.js` file there is an exports statement like:
`(module.exports={ClassA,ClassB,ClassC,ClassD,ClassE,InterfaceA,InterfaceB});`

The `index.mjs` file just looks like:

```
import ClassA from './index.js'
export default ClassA
export { ClassA }
```

Now if I import in my project like this:
`import { ClassA } from 'third-party-lib'` it works fine in `DEVELOPMENT` but breaks when trying to build for `PRODUCTION` using `vite 4.3.8` as my front-end tooling. The error is: `TypeError [Error]: ClassA is not a constructor`

What seems to work is adjusting the first line of the `index.mjs` file of the 3rd party lib to:

```
import { ClassA } from './index.js'
```

but then none of the `module.exports` from `index.js` are included except for `ClassA`. ESM and CJS interoperability is pretty challenging for me, I'm not sure how to proceed. In the `index.mjs` do I import everything from the `index.js` and then export everything, like:

```
import { ClassA, ClassB, etc. } from './index.js'
export default ClassA
export { ClassA, ClassB, etc. }
```